# writable collection questions

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

When reading the book of `Hadoop, the definitive guide`, I found the following paragraph. It seems to me that the code segment marked with yellow is an example for the scenario marked with green.

I am not clear why we have to `super(Text.class);`, and which part of the code shows that we “set the type statically” , which is marked with red.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, and one of the worst things about Hadoop, is that *everything* (input and output formats, keys, values, mappers, reducers, combiners, partitioners, comparators, ...) is constructed using reflection, with the assumption that the provided class has a 0-arg constructor.  That means you can't just use ArrayWritable as the class of your key or value because there is no 0-arg constructor that Hadoop can use to instantiate a key or value with that type.  By creating a trivial subclass like TextArrayWritable, with a 0-arg constructor, you get around this annoying limitation.  It's a slightly weird use of "statically"; the constructor is still setting the element type at runtime, even though it's a constant.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you check ArrayWritable ( Super class ); it has below constructor that is why we have to set type using super

   ArrayWritable(Class valueClass)
2. Static means we have do this compile time ( that is compiler have to know this at compile time and not at run time )